# How to prevent the navigation bar from scrolling programmatically when table view is scrolled?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, navigationbar

I am working on swift 3.0 and xcode 7.3, I have an app that comprises of a table view and a navigation bar. I haven't used the storyboard.

The problem that am facing right now is that the navigation bar also scrolls down when the table view is scrolled. I am not able to figure out how to lock the position of the navigation bar. 
Can anyone help me with this ?

My code:

```
self.title = NSLocalizedString("mdm.agent.common.home", comment: "")
   self.tableView = UITableView(frame: self.tableView.frame, style: .Grouped)

    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    let navigationBar: UINavigationBar = UINavigationBar()
   navigationBar.sizeToFit()
 self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
let navigationItem = UINavigationItem()
    navigationItem.title = NSLocalizedString("mdm.agent.common.desktopCentral", comment: "")
    navigationItem.titleView?.sizeToFit()


    navigationBar.setItems([navigationItem], animated: false)
    navigationBar.frame.size.height = 75
    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = false

self.view.addSubview(navigationBar)
 UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false
    self.tableView.backgroundView = nil
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = mdmiosagent_Constants.APP_BACKGROUND_COLOR
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.title = NSLocalizedString("mdm.agent.common.home", comment: "")
    let button : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: NSLocalizedString("mdm.agent,common.home", comment: ""), style: .Plain, target: self, action: nil)
    button.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = button
```

I have disabled the scrolling as of now .

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of the xib you have designed? or if you are doing it programmatically then post the code.

Comment: is your view controller a UiViewController or a UITableViewController? if you add a navigation bar to a table view as a subView, the navigation bar will certainly scroll with the table view

Comment: It's a tableViewController..

Comment: So should I change the superClass ?

Comment: yes, you should use a UIViewController and add both the table view and the navigation bar as subviews of the UIViewController

Comment: I did that and i removed all the ambiguous references (self.tableview....) and added UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource as well .. but all I can see is a black screen below the navigation bar and nothing else .. i did self.view.addsubview(tableview) as well

Comment: I have found the problem , it is that the frame is not getiing set .. I changed "self.tableView = UITableView(frame: self.tableView.frame, style: .Grouped)"  to "self.tableView = UITableView(frame: tableView.frame, style: .Grouped)" initially ... but now i have changed it to the self.view.bounds. But it is covering the navigation bar .. How can i bring the table view below the navigation bar ?

Comment: I don't think you have Swift 3.0 yet, its not expected until after WWDC